# Getting a fatal error when trying to open and read a file selected by the user

Tags: android, kotlin, file

I'm trying to open a JSON file stored in the running device and then read it, but I always get a fatal error when trying to open it, and I have no idea where the problem may be. I have tried using startActivityForResult but I have not been able to make it work.

Here's the error:

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
ResultInfo{who=null, request=1166053129, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/... flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.kunfundimiento.partiesqrverificator/com.kunfundimiento.partiesqrverificator.EnterDataActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.textViewData) must not be null
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5994)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:6033)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

And here's my code:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.InputStream

class EnterDataActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_data)
        val btnAddDatabase: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnAddDatabase)
        btnAddDatabase.setOnClickListener {
            openFile()
        }
        val btnScan: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnScan)
        btnScan.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@EnterDataActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }


    fun openFile() {
        getContent.launch("application/json")
    }

    private val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        if (uri!=null) {
            val input: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val size: Int = input!!.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)
            input.read(buffer)
            val output = String(buffer)
            val tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewData)
            tv.setText(output)
        }
    }

}
```

I understand the error is caused because *input* is null, but I also have checked if it is indeed null but it isn't.

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and Kotlin so bear with me please.

Thanks.